# How do I override parent class for td with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have the following rule for td's:

```css
.tab-entry-milestone .table td a { 
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

This is used for many tables.  There is one section of one table where I want the color to be `#000` instead of `#fff`.  I have tried wrapping that section in the following:

```html
 <td>
     <div id="not_white">
         <a onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;" href="#"></a>
     </div>
 </td>
```

```css
#not_white {
    color: #000;
}
```

but it does not work.  How can I fix it?

Comment: Please show the associated HTML. It matters.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="oneOff">...</div>
```

...

```
#oneOff a {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I cannot style the link because it is actually transcompiled from ruby code dynamically when the site is visited.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#not_white a { 
    color: #fff;
}
```